# How to fix jmeter error "Could not set cipher list"

Tags: jmeter

While running the jmeter script i faced an issue as “ Could not set cipher list: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256”

What can I do to fix this error?  Output below.

[image: ciphers isse]
Got ciphers issue while running the JMeter script could u please anyone suggest me how to avoid this issue

Comment: Did you find any resolution of the above error?

Comment: not yet@pankaj singhal